# EC2 connection to RDS via hostname or IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

This week, I noticed my EC2-hosted website(*.NET*) would get this error about 50% of the time when trying to connect to my RDS database instance(SQL Server Express, Medium):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Nothing has changed on either my EC2 instance or RDS instance(SQL Server Express). The error location was random and sometimes a simple page refresh would fix it.

After messing around and experimenting for quite a while, I found that the error went away when I switched my connection string from this(**connecting via hostname**):

```
<add key="strConn" value="Server=xyz.grtrtgrt.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=myDB;User Id=dbUser;password=dbPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;pooling=false;" />
```

to this(**connecting via IP**):

```
<add key="strConn" value="Data Source=1.2.3.4, 1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDB;User Id=dbUser;password=dbPassword;Trusted_Connection=false;pooling=false;"/>
```

I know we should be using the hostname to connect to an RDS, but I can't figure out why it would suddenly start throwing errors like that.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a test with the DNS resolution of your server DNS entry from that particular EC2 instance? There have been confirmed reports of the AWS internal DNS resolution failing at times. You might test this by switching to another DNS just for testing.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I just tried it and it resolved fine with my current DNS. I'll switch to a different one for a day or so but that still seems like an odd solution.